# How can I retrieve and remove a shape that has been drawn through interaction

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Using OpenLayers 3. We have:

```
var geometryType = 'Circle';
var interactionDraw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (geometryType)
});
$scope.map.addInteraction(interactionDraw);
```

We catch the 'drawend' event and do something things that doesn't matter here, worth mentionning that it returns false to eliminate the click effect.

```
interactionDraw.on('drawend', function(event){
 //event code
  return false;
};
```

How can we access to the added shape and remove it, or prevent it to appear at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, add a `collection` destination on interaction constructor and remove from it at `drawend`.

```
var collection = new ol.Collection();

draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    features: collection,
    //...
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
    console.info(collection.getLength());
    collection.pop();
});
```

**UPDATE - Try with these modifications:**

```
var collection = new ol.Collection();

draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    features: collection,
    //...
});

vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(){
    var feature = collection.item(collection.getLength() - 1);
    source.removeFeature(feature);
    collection.pop();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this deosn't prevent the drawing to be drawn and doesn't remove it.

Comment: It does remove, you can check with`collection.getLength()`. I'm looking for a layer refresh.

Comment: You're right, it was removing only from `ol.Collection`, now it removes from source as well.

Comment: This works thank you. However ... the fun thing is: since I included the code in the bigger project it's made for, the circle disappears by its own (no idea why) ... but the requirements have changed ... the circle should now remain visible ... Maybe I'll write another question later ...